# How can I check if a specific string occurs multiple times in an other string?

Tags: java, string

My code takes input from user and if there are two `"bread"` substrings, the string between them is printed. For example, `"breadjavabread"` outputs `"java"`. However, when my code only has one `"bread"` string, an error pops up. For example, `"usjdbbreaddudub"`. How can I resolve this?

```
String cheese = "no bread";
String bread = "bread";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 5; i++)
{
  String m = s.substring(i, i + 5);
  if (m.equals(bread))
  {
    cheese = s.substring(s.indexOf(bread) + bread.length(), s.lastIndexOf(bread));
  }
}

System.out.print(cheese);
```

Comment: try using split("bread") and see what that gives you. also check whether it startsWith or endsWith "bread", just in case

Comment: If you get an error, share the error message

Comment: also, you can use regexp, but anyway, which result do you need in both cases. And what is `s` in your Question?

Comment: Put `s.indexOf(bread)` and `s.lastIndexOf(bread)` into variables, check to see if they are unequal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can solve this problem. Here are 3 of them

1. Comparing `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`

   ```
   String cheese;
   String bread = "bread";
   int firstIndex = s.indexOf(bread);
   int lastIndex = s.lastIndexOf(bread);
   if (firstIndex == -1) {
       cheese = "no bread";
   } else if (lastIndex == firstIndex) {
       cheese = "only one bread";
   }
   cheese = s.substring(firstIndex + bread.length(), lastIndex);

   System.out.print(cheese);
   ```
2. Regular expressions:

   ```
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("bread(.+?)bread").matcher(s);
   if (m.find()) {
       System.out.println(m.group(1));
   } else {
       System.out.println("Not enough bread");
   }
   ```
3. Split:

   ```
   String[] parts = s.split("bread");
   if (parts.length == 3) {
       System.out.println(parts[1]);
   } else {
       System.out.println("Not enough or too much bread");
   }
   ```